# Вывод чисел из строк Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, вывод, числа

Написал программу которая при вводе чисел определяет повторяющиеся и выводит их, но возникла проблема.
При вводе двух, трех и т.п. чисел они разбиваются.

**Пример:**

Ввод: `10 20 30 10`

Вывод: `1 0`

Должно быть: `10`

Как исправить эту проблему?
Код программы:

```py
a = input().split()
a.sort()
d = []
b = 0
c = 1
for i in a[:-1]:
    if a[b] == a[c] and a[c] not in d:
        d += a[c]
    b += 1
    c += 1
print(*map(int, d))
```

Пожалуйста, объясните понятно, потому что я только учусь писать на Питоне и мне важен не ответ, а объяснение решения. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А где тут ввод?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "test.py", line 9, in <module> d += a[c]
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: Ага, значит, вводится строка символов, а никакие не числа.

Comment: d += a[c]  замените на append()

Answer (score 3):

В общем, проблема в том, что ты не задаешь тип введенных переменных. В строке `a = input().split()`
ты получаешь список строковых переменных. То есть, каждое число имеет тип `str`.

В строке `d += a[c]` у тебя добавляется не число, а каждый элемент строки отдельно, то есть, `'1'` и `'0'`. Нужно заменить эту строку на  `d.append(a[c])`

Для работы с числами лучше сразу на вводе задать тип явно: `a = list(map(int, input().split()))`

Answer (score 1):

А так не проще?

```
a = [10, 20, 30, 10, 20]

unique = set()
repetitive = set()

for num in a:
    if num not in unique:
        unique.add(num)
    else:
        repetitive.add(num)

print(*sorted(list(repetitive)))
```

можно даже чуть покороче:

```
a = [10, 20, 30, 10, 20]

unique, repetitive = set(), set()

for num in a:
    (repetitive if num in unique else unique).add(num)

print(*sorted(list(repetitive)))
```

Если же у вас на входе строка, тогда

```
a = list(map(int, text.split()))
```

т.е.

```
text = "10 20 30 10 20"

unique, repetitive = set(), set()

for num in map(int, text.split()):
    (repetitive if num in unique else unique).add(num)

print(*sorted(list(repetitive)))
```